# What are the security issues around an open websocket connection?

Tags: html, websocket

I am building an application that is using websockets.  I am only going to allow authenticated users to open a websocket connection with the server after they have logged in and have been granted a session id.

1. Once I have opened a websocket connection with an authenticated user, the current "page" then holds the details of the open websocket connection.  At this point, is this connection relatively safe?  Or should I really be checking some token on every message within my own application level protocol that comes in over the websocket?
2. Are there any known cross-site forgery type security issues?  Where someone could coop an open websocket by getting the authenticated user to execute some javascript in some manner - resulting in the ability to exploit the open websocket connection?

Answer (score 5):

1) The connection is safe, when you make it safe on the server side. So you have to send a session ID via WebSockets, verify on the server side that it is correct and mark the connection as valid. Authentication is more difficult with HTTP, because HTTP is stateless ( unlike raw TCP ). Of course it is still possible to hijack TCP connection, but it's not that easy ( see for example [this article](http://www.javvin.com/networksecurity/TCPConnectingHijacking.html) ) and if it happens, then nothing ( except for TLS ) can help you.

2) Well, if you wrap your WebSocket connection with an anonymous function like that:

```
(function() {
    var ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:1000");
    // some other stuff
})();
```

then no external JavaScript will be able to access it, so you don't have to worry about that.

Comment: With respect to #1 above - yes I am checking the cookie in the original handshake since it is a HTTP GET request to setup the connection.  The cookie has to have a valid session id through a previous authentication. So I am securely granting the connection ... it just wasn't clear what vulnerabilities might exists now with this connection sitting open and not authenticating every message...